# Are these aluminium crimps? Are they safe?

Tags: electrical, usa

[image]

Or should i change to alumiconns?

Comment: Or MAC Blocks connectors, yeah.  MAC blocks allow connecting up to 8 wires.  They have 2 voids that take up to 4 wires per void (all 4 must be same metal, so 4Al-4Cu or 4Al-4Al etc.)

Comment: Harper, so these connectors solve the aluminium wire expanding problem that can later cause fire hazard? Interesting that there is not much info about them out there.

Comment: They are lug connectors (basically a mini-Polaris or oversized Alumiconn),  so naturally, they're made of aluminum.  Aluminum is used for lugs because it's the "universal donor", it is compatible with both copper and aluminum wires. *Copper lugs can't say the same, which was the root of the problem actually*.

Comment: Those looks like standard ferrules that were tinned. That was one of the ways to crimp aluminum wire back in the 70’s. If it is 1 hole I would bet that is what you have and how they looked back then a fairly thin wall compared to aluminum. If your connection is still tight no movement in the wires they are doing there job and you can get the plastic cap that will snap over them or just retape them. (If using tape use a quality electrical tape that won’t fall off in 2-3 years. Quality tape also helps to seal the connection. I use super 88, just not the hardware store’s .98 cent special roll.